# Capture wordpress default registration form to infusionsoft

Tags: wordpress, infusionsoft

I'm not sure if this is possible. I'm trying to use the wordpress default registration form and have the information captured in infusionsoft. Before this, I tried creating a webform in infusionsoft and used that inside wordpress (from this tutorial http://infusedaddons.com/docu/InfusedWooPRO/lessons/Using_Infusionsoft_Web_Form_as_Wordpress_Registration_Form.html), infusionsoft captures the login information but it doesn't create a user inside wordpress. Is there a way to capture it using wordpress default registration form or a maybe a plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. Wordpress installation I sometimes work on uses Infusionsoft Order Form for registration, sending back HTTP POST to wordpress, to create a new user account using Optimizemember plugin.

Comment: Is this on the Paypal Pro Checkout setup?

Comment: AFAIR, it uses PayPal Express Checkout.

Comment: Thanks, also I found out that I can use iMember360.